# FFmpeg Build ERROR (/usr/bin/ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libavutil.so': No such file or)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I'm not expert on building c-files.
I want to use custom ffmpeg in my anndroid app.
But I have the below problem when building ffmpeg package with **MinGW** and **NDK-R14b**

After running bash command, after a while finally it reaches this error:

```
/usr/bin/ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libavutil.so': No such file     or directory
make: *** [libavutil/libavutil.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I know that the problem must be about to LINKER but I can't fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect permission issue, can you try with `sudo` ?

Comment: No I don't similar with linux. I run this work on windows system

Comment: Solved: The problem was MinGW!
I just replace it with GNU Make and it worked.

Comment: Can anyone to help me about this error : 
`/tmp/9747a756ee05ef34cc3fcf51eabde826/sysroot/usr/include/unistd.h:173: error: undefined reference to '__page_size'`
I set temp folder manually but **gnu make** tries to find above path.